# How to create a window/dialog without a title bar from chrome extension on chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to display a window or a dialog box without a title bar from chrome extension.  The extension plugs into file browser on Chrome OS.  I've seen some examples that use jquery to accomplish this but all of them use browser tabs and are applicable to chrome browser.  Tabs are not available to my extension so I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Please clarify, _extension_ or _app_? Your tags are contradictory.

Comment: It is an extension.  The 'app' tag must've gotten in by mistake.